# shell: exit status of a method executing remotely

Tags: shell, methods, ssh, exit, sshpass

I have a script which has 2 methods. One method executes command on remote machine and second method acts accordingly.

```
run_remote(){
sshpass -p $password ssh $user@$ipaddr /bin/bash << EOF
   if [ -e \$file ]; then
      echo "file exist"
      exit 1
   else
      echo "file doesnt exist"
   fi
EOF
   if [ check ]; then
      echo "failed"
      exit 1
   fi
}

run_local(){
   echo "run locally"
}

#main
run_remote
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
   run_local
fi
```

But even if file exist or not, it always execute run_local method.
It would be helpful if someone can tell me how to capture exit status of a method if its performing on remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

try putting exit 0 after the line echo "file doesn't exist"

Comment: Thanks rayrayray for answering the question. There was an added code after EOF which was stopping the script to send correct status code. I removed that code and it worked. I have updated the question as well so that it doesnt create confusion.